# How to load json from Azure Blob to SQL Server using SSIS?

Tags: json, sql-server, azure, ssis, azure-blob-storage

Currently I am toggling the "Blob File Source" of Text and then using a non-existent column delimiter. What this does is stores all of the json into a single row and single column. It seems like a total hack... surely there must be a better way and hence my question...

Is there a better way to consume json stored on a blob in an SSIS package and transfer it to a SQL table endpoint.

[Reference for SSIS Azure Blob Source that explains only allow two file types which seems odd.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/azure-blob-source?view=sql-server-2017)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SSIS does not have a built in component for working with JSON, which is why you are getting that result when reading from blob store.

You have two options for working with JSON within SSIS:

1. Use a Script Component to translate the JSON into your final table structure within .NET.
2. Leave the data as a single row/column and have SQL Server parse the JSON into your destination table structure.

You can find a walkthrough of these methods here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5337/import-nested-json-files-to-sql-server-with-ssis/

Comment: yeah that would be an improvement over what I'm doing... I'll check it out - mucho gracias amigo

Comment: I think that would be helpful if the data source was not Azure... the issue is that the reader for Azure blobs only plays nice with csv or similarly delimited text files and avro. To get around that I am doing the current hack I describe in original post.  Avro is apparently very similar to json, but it barfed when I tried that.